# Jump search function python

Tags: python

I'm writing some code for a project, we are supposed to be checking search speeds on different search functions. For some reason, my jump search function fails when testing it with the target index set to 0.

```
def jump_search(lyst, target):
    try:
        for i in range(0, len(lyst), int(sqrt(len(lyst)))):
            if lyst[i] > lyst.index(target):
                i = i - int(sqrt(len(lyst)))
                return target in lyst[i:]
    except:
        return False

def main():

    gen = make_data()
    data = next(gen)

    start = perf_counter()
    print(jump_search(data, data[0]))
    stop = perf_counter()
    print(f"Jump Search Elapsed Time: {stop - start} seconds\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Upon searching for the target at index 0, it ignores my if statement and reduces the value of i to below 0 and returns false. It works for all other indices. What's even more frustrating, it works as expected when I reduced the list size to something like 500 elements from 1000000.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

EDIT: By ignores my if statement, I mean that the sqrt of len(lyst) should only be subtracted from the value of i if it is greater than that of index of my target. However, for some reason, if len(lyst) is great enough, it is subtracted from i on the first pass, reducing the value of i to below 0.

What I'm trying to accomplish my function is to iterate through lyst with my for statement using jumps. When the the index of my target becomes less than that of the value of i, the intent is to return to the previous value of i and iterate through each element of the target is found and return True.

Comment: Please add a specific case in which your function fails. Also, please describe what your function is supposed to do, I.e. describe your function

Comment: Additionally, can you clarify what you mean by 'it ignores my if statement'? How/why do you think this is happening?

Comment: @kcsquared made some edits for clarification

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Added edits for clarificatioc

Comment: @NoahDonald Your question is still very very unclear to me. Please tell what the function is supposed to do, not how it does it. Give a concrete example, not that main function which is useless to us, as we do not have access to your functions

Comment: Please don't use a bare `except`, there's really never a justification for it.